# Response data is change while updating the Model value in Angular

Tags: angular

I have created a Model that receive the data from API call, When i change the Model value it reflect the res.data also, if i assign the res.data in different variable then it also reflect, please suggest if i am doing something wrong

below is the my code

```
getAttributeDetail = (nodeData: any) => {
let att = new AttributeListModel();
att.attributeDataModel = null;
console.log('nodeData', nodeData)
let apicall = {

  "emailaddress": sessionStorage.getItem('ClientemailAddress'),
  "x-access-token": sessionStorage.getItem('ClientToken'),
  "clientid": sessionStorage.getItem('Clientid'),
  "objecttypeId": nodeData.ObjectTypeId,
}
console.log('apicall', apicall)
this.TreemenuService.GetAttributeDetail(apicall).subscribe(res => {
  console.log('The Value of res.data Befor', res)
  if (res.success == 'true') {
    console.log('The Value of res.data after Sucesss', res.data)
    this.attributeList.attributeDataModel = res.data
    att.attributeDataModel = res.data
    att.attributeDataModel[0].AttributeVal = 'TEST'
    console.log('The Value of res.data modified after loop', this.attributeList.attributeDataModel )
    console.log('The Value of res.data modified after', att.attributeDataModel )
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you post some console log output?

Comment: You assign the same array (`res.data`) to both `this.attributeList.attributeDataModel` and `att.attributeDataModel`. So if you change the content of this same, unique array, bothvariable refer to this same, unique, modified array. That's the principle of references to objects.

Comment: you can use `deep copy` to avoid the change `att.attributeDataModel = [...res.data];`

Comment: @YashRami that's not a deep copy. That's a shallow copy. The new array contains references to the same objects as the original one.

Comment: @JBNizet ohh my bad if we use shallow copy then if original object change the reference object will not change am i correct ?

Comment: I can't parse that sentence. With your shallow copy, the two variables will reference two different arrays. Adding an element, or replacing an element by something else in one of the array won't affect the other array. But modifying the state of the first object in the array, for example, will also modify the state of the first object in the other one, since both arrays contain references to the same objects.

Comment: @JBNizet Is this concept of angular. How i can create different object which has content of res. data

Comment: @JBNizet Got it thanks!!!! :)

Comment: @SumantSingh no. This is how JavaScript (and basically every language on earth using pointers/references to objects) works. Yash already showed you how to create a shallow copy of the array.